# Why Floyd Warshall algorithm only needs O(n^2) space?

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, floyd-warshall

I am studying Floyd Warshall algorithm and have a quenstion. Why does this algorithm needs only O(v^2) space?

Naively, I know that it works so fine in O(v^3) but when I saw the pseudo code of O(v^2), I was curious how it might work.

```
D ← W;
   for k ← 1 to n do
      for i ← 1 to n do
          for j ← 1 to n do
            dij ← min(d_ij, d_ik + d_kj);
return D;
```

In here, we compare d_ij and d_ik + d_kj, but since there is no super script, there is possibility that d_ik or d_kj have been already updated to kth superscirpt during (for i) and (for j) iteration. Floyd warshal always compares the addition of k-1 th super script but this algorithm doesn't sometimes. How this can be true?

Comment: d is just a 2D array, so would only take v^2 space. It is true that some of the values are updated, but this does not affect the space requirements.

Comment: I understand the code how it works. But not sure how could this guarantees solution. Since sometimes it disobeys Floyd Warshall method.

Comment: The pseudo-code that you have posted is still O(v^3). What exactly do you mean by superscript?

Comment: A simple way to make in work in `O(n²)` in space is to use to matrices to store the intermediate values,  (one for `k` odd, one for `k` even), and alternate between them. Then there is no need to make a new proof for correctness since there is the guarantee that no updated values will be used.